# How to avoid apache to stop responding in MVC application

Tags: linux, apache, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, mod-mono

ASP.NET MVC4 application is running using Apache, Mono 3.2.8 and mod_mono in Debian x64 Linux

Some times in every month server stops responding:

There is also mod_mono control panel and apache server status module istalled.

Typing `mysite.com`, `mysite.com/server-status` or `mysite.com/mono` in browser waits forever.
top shows that cpu usage is almost zero and there are lot of free memory.

There is no special timeout in web.config so every thread should terminated after 110 seconds even
if it hangs.
It looks like apache stops responding, maybe max number of conncurrent connections is reached.
This is shopping cart application and search engine robots make huge amount of calls to it in every day.

How to fix or find reason of those hangups?

Is it reasonable to create cron job

```
wget --tries=1 --timeout=5  www.mysite.com || /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

which runs after every 10 minutes ? Will this restart apache if hangup occurs ?

Using `crontab -e` and adding line

```
10 * * * * wget --tries=1 --timeout=5  www.mysite.com || /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

runs check only once per hour. How to run check after every 10 minutes ?

apache2 -V returns:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Feb  1 2014 21:26:17
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/worker"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```